# Extrude face down without disturbing adjacent surfaces

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

I am new to Blender.

I am trying to make a neck for my character's head, by extruding a face on the underside of their head.

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

But when I press `e` to extrude, or drag down with the transform tool (orientation set to `Local`), I get this:

[image]

So I set the transformation orientation to `Global`, and I get this:

[image]

My character head currently:

[image]

Could anyone please guide me in the correct direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: by default the extrusion will follow the face normal (it's orientation). If it's not vertical the extrusion won't be either. To constrain on the Z axis just press Z after the extrusion. Also, if you've enabled the Mirror Clipping option it will prevent the creation of a face between the extrusion and the mirrored extrusion.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the extrusion will follow the face normal (it's orientation). If it's not vertical the extrusion won't be either. To extrude and constrain on the Z axis just press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Also, for this kind of faces that stick to the mirror axis, if you enable the *Mirror Clipping* option it will prevent the creation of a face on the axis itself.